# Enable State Recording in Blend for Visual Studio in a Windows 8 Application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, expression-blend

I am looking for a way to add the Snapped Visual State to my Windows 8 application. According to MSDN, I can do this by selecting this under Device and enabling "Enable state recording". However, this option is disabled. The only visual state shown is "". How do I enable this option so I may edit this state?

Do I need to manually create the Visual State in the XAML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a Blank page (or the Blank project), your class will inherit from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page which doesn't automatically bring in the visual state management, and you won't see any VisualStates in the XAML.

If you create one of the other page types, the page class extends LayoutAwarePage which contains the plumbing to work with the various visual states, and the visual states are seeded in the XAML.  You can manually add the following XAML to your existing page to get the design functionality, but you'll still need to manage the switches to the state when the orientation changes (something that LayoutAwarePage does for you)

```
       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
             <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscapeOrWide"/>
             <VisualState x:Name="FilledOrNarrow" />
             <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait" />
             <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait_Detail" />
             <VisualState x:Name="Snapped" />
             <VisualState x:Name="Snapped_Detail" />
          </VisualStateGroup>
       </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help, I think I'll go the route of converting the project to run in a LayoutAwarePage. That seems much simpler. Thanks again.

Comment: However, even if I do that and convert it the Enable state recording option is disabled. Further, I managed to find a Microsoft tutorial using Visual States and could not get the state recording to work with that either. [ tutorial: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Snap-Sample-2dc21ee3 ]

Comment: try this to ensure the feature itself isn't 'broken' - create a brand new project in a new solution using the Grid App template. Does Enable State Recording work on GroupDetailPage.xaml?

Comment: Well, it works for a Grid Project, however, mine is now being weird. It compiles in Visual Studio, but throws an exception in Blend (DirectoryNotFoundException). I think I might just start my UI over. It's got a number of problems that can't be easily fixed without a rewrite anyway and this is frustrating me more. I've got 11 more days until the release. Thanks for your help Jim.